# Perform jquery action on the html thats returned by another action?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a piece of code that loads comments inside a div  when the page loads.

```
$.get("ajax_getcomments.php", { itemid: <? echo $id; ?>, type: 1 },
    function(data){
        $('#comments').html(data.comment_data);
    }, "json");
```

Inside those results, here is a link attached to each comment

```
<a href="/ajax_action.php?deletecomment=ID" class="delete_comment"></a>
```

When that link is pressed, the entire comment div should disappear out of view. I use the following code:

```
$('.delete_comment').click(function() {
        var comment_id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
        var objPDiv = $(this).parent().parent();
        $.get('./ajax_action.php', {id:comment_id, action: 'delete_comment', ajax: 1}, function(data) {
            objPDiv.animate({ opacity: 'hide' }, "slow");
        });
        return false;
    });
```

The issue is that... it doesn't work on the html that is fetched from ajax_getcomments.php by jquery.

if I copy/paste the html into the  and don't perform the initial GET call, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `.click()` only works for existing elements that match your selector. To bind to future elements, you need to use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$('.delete_comment').live('click', function() {
        var comment_id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
        var objPDiv = $(this).parent().parent();
        $.get('./ajax_action.php', {id:comment_id, action: 'delete_comment', ajax: 1}, function(data) {
            objPDiv.animate({ opacity: 'hide' }, "slow");
        });
        return false;
});
```

`.live()` attaches a handler to the event for all current and future elements that match your selector. So when jQuery sees that you have inserted a new element into the DOM that matches the selector used in `.live()`, it will automatically attach a handler for the `onClick` event to the new element.

Comment: To complete this answer: `live` is basically a `bind` which will be triggered when a new object is created. Thus, from that point onwards, the bind will be applied to any element, even if it's new.

Answer (score 1):

The event (click, in this case) is attached to all elements '.delete_comment' at the time the javascript is originally executed (usually at page load). If you create new elements later, the click event is not attached to them unless you specifically tell jQuery to attach it.

You can do this via the live function:

```
$('.delete_comment').live('click', function() {
    // Your code
});
```

This will instruct jQuery to bind your function to the .delete_comment element whenever it appears, now or in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You should watch for delete actions at the level of the container div, using [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

```
$('#comments').delegate('.delete_comment','click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    // your deletion code here
});
```